# Mac Mail Server 10.9.5 keeps getting password couldn't be set error

Tags: time-machine, security, password, user-account, server.app

I am trying to change an mailbox password but each time attempt to I cannot procceed and I am faced with this error:

> The password could not be set. In order to set the password of a user with an Open Directory Password, your own password type must be Open Directory. Administrators with other password types cannot set the password of a user with an Open Director password.

I have authenticated as diradmin user to no avail. Happened after I restored from Time Machine backup when setting up from old server.

I also get error below when trying to create a new user in the Server App.

[image: existing connection is not authenticated and the old password is not present: password change denied]

Excerpt from my log:

```
                                               => bdb_idl_insert_key: c_put id failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Jan 19 14:47:32 server.•••.co.uk slapd[12508]: conn=25923 op=3: attribute "entryCSN" index add failure
Jan 19 14:47:32 server.•••.co.uk slapd[12508]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Jan 19 14:47:32 server.•••.co.uk slapd[12508]: conn=-1 op=0: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
Jan 19 14:48:08 server.•••.co.uk slapd[12508]: => bdb_idl_delete_key: c_get failed: DB_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Locker killed to resolve a deadlock (-30994)
Jan 19 14:48:08 server.•••.co.uk slapd[12508]: conn=25992 op=3: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
```